# Необходимо переместить всех пользователей, находящихся в голосовых каналах на голосовой канал. где нахожусь я discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Пытаюсь в боте написать команду, выполнение которой перемещало бы всех пользователей из разных голосовых каналов на голосовой канал, где нахожусь я.

Я просто не понимаю как это впринципе возможно.

```html
@quant.command()
@has_permissions ( administrator = True )
async def mtm ( ctx ):
    for guild in quant.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            ??????????????
```

Дальше моих знаний не хватает чтобы даже приблезительно составить алгоритм. Буду благодарен за помощь. Конкретно в этом случае чтение документации мне никак не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
@quant.command()
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def mtm(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.guild.voice_channels:
        for member in channel.members:
            await member.move_to(ctx.author.voice.channel)
```